# How to add data in my reducer based on ID

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using ReactJS and Redux, and I want to add my data to my reducer but in this way :
when I receive my action.payload : it contains ID and DATA property, and the goal is to create(if not exist) a property with ID's value and put the data property into.

Example :
When the payload is {111, {name: 'test',age : 25}} , It should create (if not exist) a property in my reducer like this :

```js
MyReducer : {
    clientData : {
       111 : {name : 'test', age : 25}
}
}
```

And if i want to add another payload : {2222, {name :'toto' : age : 30}} the result should look like :

```js
MyReducer : {
    clientData : {
       111 : {name : 'test', age : 25},
       2222  : {name : 'toto', age : 30}
}
}
```

And in the case when the id exist in my reducer , it should remplace data with the new action.payload.data values.

I've tried this :

```js
case 'ADD_CLIENT_DATA_SUCCESS':
            const { id, record } = action.payload;
            console.log(action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                clientData: {
                    ...state.clientData,
                    id: record,
                },
            };
```

But it take id as static variable, the result is this :

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this please ?
Thank you

**EDIT : I've edited my code but for the new data entered, it not rendered as array of object..**
This is my code   :

```js
case 'ADD_CLIENT_DATA_SUCCESS':
            const { id, record } = action.payload;
            console.log(state.clientData[id]);
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                clientData: {
                    ...state.clientData,
                    [id]: [state?.clientData[id] || null, record],
                },
            };
```

Expected result when adding NEWDATA to existed id in my reducer :  :

```js
MyReducer : {
    clientData : {
       111 : {name : 'test', age : 25},
       2222  : [{name : 'toto', age : 30}, {name : 'NEWDATA', age : 40}]
}
}
```

Comment: Hint: use the dynamic property for objects (Bracket Notation).  
`clientData: {...state.clientData, [id]: record},`

Comment: What about if I have an array instead of record ? how to spread old data and add new data into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `id` variable as a key so you need to wrap it with `[]`

```
   case 'ADD_CLIENT_DATA_SUCCESS':
        const { id, record } = action.payload;
        console.log(action.payload);
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            clientData: {
                ...state.clientData,
                [id]: record,
            },
        };
```

---

Read [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) for more info

Comment: What about if I have an array instead of record ? how to spread old data and add new data into ?

Comment: @Duchere you could use (*assuming the `record` is always a new one*) `[id]: [...(state.clientData[id] || []), record]`

Comment: I get an error 'Uncaught TypeError: (clientData || []) is not iterable' 
Because clientData is an Object..

Comment: You are missing the `[id]` part. It is `clientData[id] || []`

Comment: `return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    clientData: {
     ...state.clientData,
     [id]: [...(state.clientData[id] || []), record],
    },
   };
`

Comment: I get th same error ..

Comment: @Duchere that happens, because you want to have it as either an object or an array. That is just asking for trouble down the road. You should keep it always an array and if it only has one "record" it should be an array with a single record.

Comment: Any ideas how to achieve it please ? I'm trying some other solutions.
`return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    clientData: {
     ...state.clientData,
     [id]: [state.clientData[id], record].flat(2),
    },
   };`

Comment: @Duchere, how do you end up with some `id` having an object as a value in the state ? The code i posted in the comment, should handle the first case as well, assuming you have not set it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

put id in [] to use the dynamic variable and not a string id :

```
         ...state,
   loading: false,
                clientData: {
                    ...state.clientData,
                    [id]: record,
                },
            };
```

Comment: What about if I have an array instead of record ? how to spread old data and add new data into ?

Comment: very easily : `[...oldArray, newItemInArray]`

Comment: Please take a look in my edited post, I have an error when trying your solution

Comment: I saw your update, indeed. But i'm not sure what you're trying to build here. Are you meaning that your datas in clientData can be an object, or an array of object. 
But can it be one or the other or can it be both, I mean, if you have an id `id1` which is an object, can it be tranfrom to an array in the future or since it was instanciated as an object, it will remain as it is forever ?

Comment: you are missing the spread operators ` ... ` in front of `state?.clientData[id] ` and if record is an array too, you need to put them to in front of record :

```
 clientData: {
                    ...state.clientData,
                    [id]: [...state?.clientData?.[id] , record],
                }

```

Comment: I've tried your code but it's not working.. and that's because i can't spread an object...
My goal is to create an array in each [id], and this array will contains all objects related to this id.. 

This is my new code :


`case 'ADD_CLIENT_DATA_SUCCESS':
   const { id, record } = action.payload;
   console.log(state.clientData[id]);
   return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    clientData: {
     ...state.clientData,
     [id]: [...(state.clientData[id] || []), record],
    },
   };`

Comment: Yes, because you clientData is an object in the first place (which is king of weird to first add a single object that becomes later an array of that object). You should have clientData instanciation as an empty array first and always add by replacing with a new array including the old Array and the new item as ` [...state.oldArray , payload.newItem]`